# PowerShell Remote from VSTS Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to invoke PowerShell commands on my VM remotely.
I added "Run PowerShell on Target Machines" task in my pipeline. I provided: IP, username and password of my remote VM.
Here's the error that I'm getting:

> Unable to create pssession. Error: 'Connecting to remote server
>    failed with the following error message : WinRM
>   cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name
>   is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a
>   firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access
>   from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for
>   public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same
>   local subnet. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.'

On my remote VM, I did:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
Set-NetFirewallRule -Name "WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-PUBLIC" -RemoteAddress Any
```

These commands were mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6

What else can I do?

Comment: Not only the firewall rule in the VM, but you should also add the rule in the NSG associated with the VM.

Comment: @CharlesXu Sorry, forgot to mention - I added "Allow" rule for both 5985 and 5986, so this shouldn't be the problem. IP that I use is of course public and accessible (I can RDP to that VM without issue)

Comment: Do you also enable the WinRM in the VM? And you add the NSG rule both in the subnet and nic for the VM? Can you remote connect through WinRM locally?

Comment: @CharlesXu WinRM is enabled already by Enable-PSRemoting. My subnet does not have any NSG assigned, I added my rules on my NIC's NSG

Comment: Do you follow the steps in [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops)?

Comment: Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force

Comment: Run above wsman command on the client machine.

Comment: @CharlesXu Your link had other links that helped me. Looks like certificate is necessary on target machine. I created a self-signed one and it worked. I don't really udnerstand why it's needed since PowerShell task is run with "-SkipCACheck" flag. if you post some answer here, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Moerwald I cannot change anything on client since I'm using Azure DevOps's hosted pool of VMs - these are maintained by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the PowerShell scripts on the Target Machine Task through WinRM, the Windows Machine, you need to configure the WinRM in the target machine first. There are two protocols for you: HTTP and HTTPS. The HTTPS is more safe and recommended. If you use the HTTPS, then you need to open port 5986 in the firewall and install a self-signed certificate. You can follow the steps in [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops).

For your issue in the comment, you can find the description in **Test Certificate** and I think the reason is that you use a self-certificate which you create.

Comment: @Charlex Xu - although documentation mentions "Test Certificate" option, it is not available in the Task options.

Comment: @Loreno Yeah, there is not an exact explanation. But I believe it's the most possible reason :)